# Wrapping text around a custom view

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, android-glide

I've created a custom view with two drawable images; the first image is displayed across the whole width of the top of the screen with aspect ratio adjusted accordingly. My second image is placed just below the top image on the left-hand side.

Now is there a way to efficiently display text on the right of the second image wrapping if necessary. My custom view is as followed:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.GlideDrawable;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.animation.GlideAnimation;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.SimpleTarget;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.ViewTarget;

import java.util.Random;

import demo.example.com.customarrayadapter.R;

import static android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getDrawable;

public class AspectRatioImageView extends TextView {
    ImageView ivTop, ivLower;
    ViewTarget viewTarget;
    private ViewTarget<AspectRatioImageView, GlideDrawable> viewTarget0,
        viewTarget1, viewTarget2;
    AspectRatioImageView customView0, customView1;
    private static Drawable mDrawableLeft, mDrawableRight;
    private Bitmap mBitmap0,mBitmap1;
    private static final int mColumnCount = 2;
    private static int mCount = 0;
    private int mLheight, mRheight;

public void initialize( final Context context) {
    Glide.
            with(context)
    .load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780//uS1SkjVviraGfFNgkDwe7ohTm8B.jpg")
            .asBitmap()
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation anim) {
                    // Do something with bitmap here.
                    setLeftDrawable(bitmap);
                }
            });
    Glide.
            with(context)
            //.load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780//imSjsW6QRkH7fvhnqhQgjnbBBtd.jpg")
            .load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342//uS1SkjVviraGfFNgkDwe7ohTm8B.jpg")

            .asBitmap()
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation anim) {
                    // Do something with bitmap here.
                    setRightDrawable(bitmap);
                }
            });
}

public void setLeftDrawable(Bitmap bitmap){
    mDrawableLeft = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    updateContentBounds();
    invalidate();
}

public void setRightDrawable(Bitmap bitmap){
    mDrawableRight = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    updateContentBounds();
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    if (w != oldw || h != oldh) {
        updateContentBounds();
    }
}

public AspectRatioImageView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
    //if (!isInEditMode())
        initialize(context);
}

public AspectRatioImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
    //if (!isInEditMode())
        initialize(context);
}

public AspectRatioImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    //if (!isInEditMode())
        initialize(context);
}

public int getCustomWidth(){
    return getWidth();
}

public int getCustomHeight(){
    return (mLheight + mRheight);
}

public void updateContentBounds(){
    if (mDrawableLeft != null) {
        double ratio = (double) mDrawableLeft.getIntrinsicHeight() / mDrawableLeft.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int left = 0;
        int top = 0;
        int w = left + getWidth();
        int h = (int) (top + (getWidth() * ratio));
        mLheight = h;
        //int h = (int) (top + (mDrawable0.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 2);
        mDrawableLeft.setColorFilter(0xffff0000, PorterDuff.Mode.LIGHTEN);
        mDrawableLeft.setBounds(left, top,
                w, h);
    }

    if (mDrawableRight != null) {
        double ratio = (double) mDrawableRight.getIntrinsicHeight() / mDrawableRight.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int wleft = 0;
        int wtop = mLheight;
        int ww = wleft + getWidth() / 2;
        int wh = (int) (wtop + ((getWidth() / 2)*ratio));
        mRheight = (int) ((getWidth() / 2)*ratio);
        mDrawableRight.setColorFilter(0xdfef0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        mDrawableRight.setBounds(wleft, wtop,
                ww, wh);
    }
    if ((mDrawableLeft != null) && (mDrawableRight != null))
        setCompoundDrawables(mDrawableLeft, null, mDrawableRight, null);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //super.onDraw(canvas);
    // Log.d("LOG", " ***********onDraw()");
    if (mDrawableLeft != null) {
        mDrawableLeft.draw(canvas);
    }
    if (mDrawableRight != null) {
        mDrawableRight.draw(canvas);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    updateContentBounds();
    Log.d("LOG"," ****width:"+getCustomWidth()+" ****height:"+getCustomHeight());
    Drawable bg = mDrawableRight;
    if (bg != null) {
        //Get the width measurement
        int widthSize = View.resolveSize(getCustomWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);

        //Get the height measurement
        //int height = widthSize * bg.getIntrinsicHeight()/bg.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int heightSize = View.resolveSize(getCustomHeight() , heightMeasureSpec);
        //int heightSize = View.resolveSize(height , heightMeasureSpec);

        //MUST call this to store the measurements
        setMeasuredDimension(widthSize, heightSize);


    } else {
        setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
}
```

My custom views XML:

```
<demo.example.com.customarrayadapter.customviews.AspectRatioImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:src="@drawable/icecream"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:foregroundGravity="top"/>
```

Thank you.

Comment: use `android.text.Layout`

Comment: Thanks can you be more specific?

Comment: or if you are lazy, refer to this: http://dev.androidteam.ru/snippets/textview/leadingmarginspan2

Comment: Yes, i'm lazy. Thank you :)